# swip between images that downloaded from a server

Tags: android

i have images that downloaded from a server and it downloaded into grid view  when i clicked an image it opened in another activity i need to swip between images when opened into the second activity what is the wrong in my code?

```
public class customswitcher extends PagerAdapter{
Context c;
ArrayList<photos> sites;
LayoutInflater inflater;
public customswitcher(Context c, ArrayList<photos> sites)
{
    this.c = c;
    this.sites = sites;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 0;
}
@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view== (LinearLayout) object;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.imageswitcher,container,false);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv);
    photos photos = sites.get(position);
    Picasso.with(c).load(photos.getImage()).into(imageView);
    container.addView(view);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
}
```

}

```
public class Funny extends AppCompatActivity {
MyDataBase dataBase = new MyDataBase(Funny.this);
String url = "http://javawy.fulba.com/yphotos.php";
ProgressDialog dialog;
String pw;
List<photos> list;
photos posts;
customfunny adapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_funny);
    list=  dataBase.getallcontacts();
    final GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray jsonArray = object.getJSONArray("photos");
                 list = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
                {
                    JSONObject object1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                     pw = object1.getString("image");
                     posts = new photos(pw);
                    dataBase.AddnewContact(posts);
                    list.add(posts);
                }
                dialog.dismiss();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(Funny.this,"اتصل بالانترنت لتحصل علي احيث الصور",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
    adapter = new customfunny(Funny.this,list);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int i, long l) {
          photos photos = (com.example.yasser.ahlysc.photos) gridView.getItemAtPosition(i);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Funny.this,SelectedImage.class);
            intent.putExtra("one",photos.getImage());
            startActivity(intent);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(Funny.this);
    dialog.setTitle("downloading");
    dialog.setMessage("جاري تحديث الصور....انتظر");
    dialog.show();
    Volley.newRequestQueue(Funny.this).add(stringRequest);
}
```

}

```
public class SelectedImage extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_selected_image);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    String s = i.getStringExtra("one");
    ArrayList<photos> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new photos(s));
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vp);
    customswitcher customswitcher = new customswitcher(SelectedImage.this,list);
    pager.setAdapter(customswitcher);
}
```

}

Comment: to swipe? SelectedImage knows only one photo, try adding more.

Comment: any photo i clicked from funny activity opened into SelectedImage

Comment: `list.add(new photos(s));`there is only one photo added here.

Comment: thank you my frined i send the all list from funny activity and the code run well